# I am unable load angular app after deployment

Tags: angular, angular8, mime-types

After deploying an Angular app on cloud, a blank page is shown when URL is reached and console is showing MIME type errors.

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script
> but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME
> type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: Can you see the content of the reponse when you load the web page?

Comment: Could you provide more info? like the url the app is deployed to? (also the source code would be great if it's public)

Comment: Which service are you using? In case GCP, you may have to specify mime_type in app.yaml.

Comment: its in private cloud and app is not public.